# I need Android USB driver of Turkcell Maxi Plus 5

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, usb-drivers

I have Turkcell Maxi Plus 5, and I didn't find a USB driver for it. Where can I get the correct driver for it?

I have windows 7 32 bit

Comment: Are you sure it needs a specific driver? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You will need to [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/50695/edit) your questions and provide a few more details on what you want to achieve: Using ADB? Accessing the storage?

Comment: I wil use adb to debug my applications